# Implement a breadth first graph traversal upto a given depth

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement a breadth first graph traversal that returns the number of paths from one node to another, but only through a given number of nodes.

For example given a list of Nodes A, B, C, D, E, if I want to know the number of different paths I can get from A to D, but only if the path has no more than 2 stops. A-B-D, A-E-D would be considered acceptable, but A-B-E-D would be too many stops, so the answer would be 2 paths.

I am trying to implement this algorithm, but I am not sure how I can keep track of the depth, so that my search only goes n levels deep.

Here is my codeI have written so far. The problem lies in searchNumPaths() method.

```
public class PathSearch{
private int maxSearches;
private int pathCount;
private int numPaths;
private String node;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> path;
ArrayList<Node> visited;

public PathSearch(int maxSearches, int pathCount) {
    node = "";
    this.maxSearches = maxSearches;
    this.pathCount = pathCount;
    path = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    visited = new ArrayList<Node>();
}

public int searchNumPaths(HashMap<String, Node> graph, Node startLocation, String endLocation, Queue<String> queue) {
    //queue.add(startLocation.getLocation());
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        node = queue.remove();
        System.out.println("\n" + node +"\n");
        for (Edge realPath: graph.get(node).getNeighbors()) {
                node = realPath.getEndLocation();
                System.out.println(node);
                queue.add(node);
                if (node.equals(endLocation)) {
                    numPaths++;
                }   
        }
        pathCount++;
        if (pathCount>6){
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<queue.size(); i++) {
            searchNumPaths(graph, graph.get(queue.peek()), endLocation, queue);
            queue.remove();
        }

    }
    return numPaths;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Train train = new Train();
    Graph graph = new Graph(train.readFile("input.txt"));
    LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
    queue.add("A");
    PathSearch great = new PathSearch(10, 0);
    HashMap<String, Node> map = graph.returnMap();
    Node node = graph.returnMap().get("A");
    String nodeTwo = graph.returnMap().get("C").getLocation();
    //System.out.println(queue.remove());
    System.out.println("Number of paths: " + great.searchNumPaths(map, node, nodeTwo, queue));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `QueueNode` class that contains the current string you put in your queue together with a number that indicates the depth of the node. You could then continue the search until you encounter a node with a depth that is too high. Something like this (`T` is a `String` in your case):

```
public class QueueNode<T> {

    T value;
    int depth;

    public QueueNode(T value, int depth) {
        this.value = value;
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    // And so on.. Getters etc.

}
```

When you create new `QueueNode` objects, you can just set the depth to one greater than the depth of the current node.

By doing this, you could add something like this to your `searchNumPaths` function (after the call to `queue.remove()`):

```
if (node.getDepth() > maxDepth) {
    return numPaths;
}
```

Note that this only works if your queue is guaranteed to return nodes with increasing depth. This is always true for a breadth-first search, but if you're going to change it to an A-star search or something later, this assumption breaks.

Comment: Be aware that if you store the depth, you'll need to re-calculate/update the depths every time nodes are moved. (Some _may_ even consider this as duplicated knowledge, but it's probably not a huge deal)

Comment: The problem is that the depth of the nodes change depending on the start and end locations. Also, Nodes should be able to reach themselves depending on the path they take. Would this be able to account for these conditions?

Comment: Oh I see how it would work. Thank you so much. I would just increment the next depth based on the previous node.